# How to approach writing the proper Gherkin line in "technical Gherkin"

Tags: syntax, gherkin

I'm required to write some so-called "technical gherkins", which means that using the gherkin keywords and structure must write the scenario not from the "what" aspect (example: when user saves the record then the record is updated) but detailing the "how" (example: when the user clicks the save button then the record is updated and displayed in the list). I don't really find any documentation on how to do it properly. Does anyone out there have some experience with this?

This is the case. Please note the lines in CAPITALS - would using the second version be good practice? Especially since it would have an OR operator in it. Any input is appreciated.

Version 1:

Given the user is on the "User groups" panel

And one user group is selected

When user clicks on "Editing of user group" button

And the "User group edit" window appears

AND USER MODIFIES ANYTHING IN THE "PERMISSION" SECTION

And clicks on the "Save" button

Then a confirmation message is displayed

And the permissions of the User group are updated

Version 2:

Given the user is on the "User groups" panel

And one user group is selected

When user clicks on "Editing of user group" button

And the "User group edit" window appears

AND USER CLICKS ANY CHECKBOX IN THE "PERMISSION" SECTION OR
MODIFIES THE USERS IN THE USER LIST

And clicks on the "Save" button

Then a confirmation message is displayed

And the permissions of the User group are updated

Answer (score 0):

Your "technical gherkins" is not maintenance frienldy. It will produce a lot of dupliated blocks in your result test suite. So you will spend a lot of time updating the tests as the project evolves.
Using OR is not an accepted approach. This is a test smell called 'Conditional Test Logic'.

If you do care about both conditions you should use Scenario outline

```
Scenario outline: 
...
AND user performs an <action>
...
Examples: Actions
| action                                          |
| CLICK ANY CHECKBOX IN THE "PERMISSION" SECTION  |
| MODIFY THE USERS IN THE USER LIST               |
```

If you dont care, use the first statement from your example.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Yes, I am not a fan of this approach either.